# What is true about thrust?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure

Our book says the force acting on an object perpendicular to the surface is called thrust

If two forces are acting on  an object perpendicular to the surface both of them will be called thrust or the net force will be called thrust?

***I am a School kid please explain kindly and simply***

Comment: Sorry, but many textbooks written outside of the English-speaking, especially high school textbooks, just make up words that nobody else uses. In America at least, people don't use the word "thrust" that way, so I don't know how to answer your question. You should instead ask your teacher what they _think_ it means.

Comment: There are a lot of Indians in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies) who might be able to help you.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on "thrust" and I'd suggest you start there.

Comment: @StephenG that is diferent thrust

Comment: You have to explain how it is different.  The only thing your description sounds like is a ["normal force"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force), which is a very general term.

Comment: this sounds like a seismologist definition of thrust. As in thrust fault vs strike/slip.

Comment: @StephenG It also says thrust/area is pressure if it can help you help me

Answer (score 1):

Thrust is a reaction force described quantitatively by Newton's third law.

When a system expels mass in one direction, the accelerated mass will cause a force of equal magnitude but opposite direction on that system. The force applied on a surface in a direction perpendicular to the surface is called thrust.

In the macro world you can have more than 1 system expelling mass in a direction adding thrust to the system as a whole.  Think of a rocket with multiple rocket motors.  They are all adding thrust to the rocket as a whole.

Each of the three Space Shuttle Main Engines could produce a thrust of 1.8 MN, and each of the Space Shuttle's two Solid Rocket Boosters 14.7 MN, together 29.4 MN.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: no that is different